# Powershell Script to run querieis against Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following Powershell script:

```
$domainObj = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$PDC = ($domainObj.PdcRoleOwner).Name
$SearchString = "LDAP://"
$SearchString += $PDC + "/"
$DistinguishedName = "DC=$($domainObj.Name.Replace('.', ',DC='))"
$SearchString += $DistinguishedName
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]$SearchString)
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$Searcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$Searcher.filter="samAccountType=805306368"
$Result = $Searcher.FindAll()
Foreach($obj in $Result)
{
    Foreach($prop in $obj.Properties)
    {  
        $prop
    }
    Write-Host "------------------------"
}
```

I need this amend this to do the following, but I am unsure how to apply the correct filters, which I believe need to go in `$Searcher.filter`:

1. Change the script to only return members of the Domain Admins group.
2. Change the script to return all computers in the domain.
3. Add a filter to only return computers running Windows 10.

Comment: are there any reasons you don't use `Get-ADComputer` and `Get-ADUser`/`Get-ADGroup`?

Comment: cmdlets like Get-ADUser are only on DCs by default. The point of the script is to be able to query without those.

Comment: you can install the rsat tools to have the features available

Comment: The point of the script is to be able to query without those.

Comment: take a look at the script https://github.com/lazywinadmin/PowerShell/blob/master/AD-COMPUTER-Get-DomainComputer/Get-DomainComputer.ps1 it does query for computers you can then filter the output like `Get-Domaincomputer -DomainDN 'DOMAINNAME' -ComputerName * | where {operatingsystem -like 'Windows 10*'}`

Comment: and this scripts gets the users of a group https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-AD-group-members-6e6c8a9f

Comment: the scripts show you how it can be done. SO is not a scripting service - you should know and understand what your script does - again - you can do this by looking into the links provided. nevertheless i will remain silent from now on.

Comment: For domain admins --> `$searcher.filter = 'SamAccountName=Domain Admins'; $searcher.findall().properties.member`. For computers --> `$searcher.filter = 'objectclass=computer'; $searcher.findall()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
$domainObj = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$PDC = ($domainObj.PdcRoleOwner).Name
$searchString = "LDAP://{0}/DC={1}" -f $PDC,$domainObj.Name.Replace('.', ',DC=')
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]$SearchString)
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$Searcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain

# Domain Admins
$Searcher.filter='samAccountName=Domain Admins'
$DAs = $Searcher.FindAll().Properties.Member

# All Computers
$Searcher.filter='objectClass=Computer'
$Computers = $Searcher.FindAll()

# Windows 10
$Computers | Where {
    $_.Properties.OperatingSystemVerison -match '^10\D' -and $_.Properties.OperatingSystem -notmatch 'Server'
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I couldn't get this to work. I did however find a solution and I will post that shortly. I did use your solution for  returning all computers in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

get all domain admins (in ad group "Administrators"):

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators
```

get computers using Windows 10

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -like 'Windows 10*'}
```

for reference please see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps

Comment: This is not the answer. I did specifically say I need to amend the script. cmdlets like Get-ADComputer are only installed on DCs by default.

Comment: Do you have access to the DC?